# CIVIC tokens in old Jaxx address

Tags: jaxx

I participated in the Civic crowd sale and tokens can be seen in the address I provided via etherscan.
The address I provided was a Jaxx address as they advertised that they would be compatible.
The Jaxx version I was using was IOS version 1.1.5
I use the desktop chrome extension version with the same 12 word seed.
The CVC coin option is not in the phone app yet but is in the chrome extension.
My CVC coins are not in the chrome extension wallet.

Do I need to add ether/gas to the address I provided?

Do I need to import the ethereum private key from the old phone version into the chrome extension version?

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: If you can see your tokens in etherscan then very likely they are in your account. Wait a bit to show up in the chrome extension but if it fails you should contact jaxx support, it may be just a glitch. Ios version always lags behind because of apple's approval process.

Answer (score 1):

You can export your JAXX private key and import it in MyEtherWallet to work around limitations in JAXX user interface:

https://shapeshift.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000884030-I-sent-my-ETH-token-to-my-ETH-wallet-on-Jaxx-or-visa-versa-need-to-extract

Answer (score 0):

Note that tokens are never "stored" in your ethereum address or in your wallet. they are always stored in the contract (Civic ICO contract in this case), and that contract have a mapping table (ethereum address owns xx Civic Tokens).

If you control the address (ie it's not your exchange address), then it's usually only a matter of your wallet supporting that token (know about it).

If you check your address on etherscan.io you can validate if you truly are a CIVIC token owner, or better yet check the CIVIC contract address directly.

https://etherscan.io/token/Civic#readContract

Enter your address under bullet 6 (balance of)